# Selenium - running scripts gets slower when total scripts is around 2000 lines

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a My Profile Page to automate, for which I am using Selenium Latest version with Java. The Page mainly contains validations like -

1. Various invalid inputs for User Name
2. Various invalid input for Password and Confirm Password
3. Various invalid input for Secret Question
   4 . Similar for Phone number, Primary email, secondary email, Address fields,

Totally my scripts are around 2000 lines and total testcases comes around 200.

But when I reach in middle like around 100 testcases itself, the browser becomes slower in execution and pop ups opening and all becomes slower.

I have noticed this major in Google chrome.

Is it because of Memory leaks in my selenium scripts or any other cause. Please help me.

Comment: When the test is running, have you noticed the memory ram free space getting lesser than before?How much lesser when the test starts and ends?

Comment: I havent tried that. But as a general doubt - IS it better to run the whole script together once or divide it in parts and run each section separately ?

Comment: I don't know how selenium works in java or if there is any memory leak, but in c# i already worked with 5000+ lines without problems. I'm not the best person to assert if there is any problem in your java code, but if you don't find any solution about the subject, I think the better solution is split your test, and each of the new (and smaller) test runs specifics validations, as one for each inputs or for each kind of test (max lenght, type of input etc)

Comment: are you running all 100 test cases on the same instance of the browser?